# Tridion.Logging missing one of its dependencies

Tags: 2013, core-service, c#, logging

I am having issues finding the proper dll reference for Tridion.Logging. Currently I am referncing/using:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client; 
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields; 
using Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement; 
using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;  
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService;
```

but I still recieve the error :

Result Message:

> Test method *XXXXXX* threw exception:  System.IO.FileLoadException:
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.Logging, Version=6.1.0.25,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990297/error-when-accessing-core-service-from-a-client-machine#

And tried some of the solution given but no luck. What dependencies does Tridion.Logging have that I need to add?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to use this in, what type of application? You should only reference `Tridion.logging` in an event handler or a Template Building Block, but in your references I see a mix of core service and TOM.NET API, so it looks like you are creating something with the wrong APIs

Comment: yes I realize I do. I was trying out some answers from the post I referenced in my question. Here is what I originally started with:                               using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Templating;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client;                                          I am trying to write unit tests for our custom Tridion C# code but I am unable to see the true error becuse of this current error.

Comment: Edit your question and update it with details on what you are building, and where it should run etc. then we can answer if you are using the right APIs. From that I expect we will flow into the part of either eliminating the error, or getting to its root cause (seems an incorrect DLL is being referenced, but if you shouldn't even be using it, it's no point in sorting out which one)

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are referring to the wrong version of Tridion.Logging dll (Tridion 2011 instead of the one from Tridion 2013).

Please check the Tridion.Logging.dll versions for Tridion 2013 they should be 7.x and for Tridion 2011 they should be 6.x

Comment: since there is no using statement pointing to `Tridion.Logging`, I'm guessing that one of the other using statements is referring to a DLL from a different Tridion version actually.

Comment: opened up the dll and looked in the version folder. it is  Pr o d u c t V e r s i o n   7 . 1 . 0 . 5 2

Comment: @BartKoopman I see what you are saying I will look. I there an easy way to figure it out?